# Is it possible to safely remove partitions on an existing dual boot machine?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a dual boot machine containing Ubuntu and and Windows XP partitions.

I'd like to remove the Ubuntu partition and have only Windows (and use VirtualBox within Windows for Ubuntu).

1. Can I safely erase the contents of the Linux partition and still be able to expect to boot into Windows (or, does the Grub bootloader stuff live in the Linux partition?)
2. How can I increase the size of the existing Windows partition to include the whole drive without reinstalling Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Gparted should allow you to extend the windows partition without reinstalling windows.  The Windows XP fdisk utility (if I remember correctly) has a option /mbr which will restore the mbr to the windows version.

Comment: Be sure to backup Windows before doing this, just in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to remove linux, just make sure to rebuild the bootloader. do this by booting from a recovery disk. I think the command in the command prompt is bootrec.exe/fixmbr. This has worked for me in the past when removing linux installations